# Write an algorithm for finding the minimum element

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Given array A=[31, 40, 41, 16, 41, 58,20], min algorithm returns 16. Write an algorithm for finding the minimum element.

Comment: What good is dumping an assignment on a community?

Comment: Since $A$ is fixed, what about just `return 16`?

Comment: You can simply Google, "find the minimum element in an array C++". Most early computer science homework has a plethora of online examples. Make sure you fully understand these examples before you use them. Get some scratch paper and write out how this algorithm works.

Answer (score 2):

Algorithm:

Traverse the array and compare with every element to update the minimum element.

Code:

```
int getMin(vector<int> &A){
    int minElement = INT_MAX;
    for(auto num: A){
        minElement = min(minElement, num);
    }
    return minElement;
}
```

Algorithm Analysis:

Time Complexity:

If given input has `n` elements, then we have to go through every element to identify the minimum of them all. It is easy to prove by contradiction that we have to compare with each and every element. So the time complexity is `Omega(n)` or `O(n)` or `Theta(n)`.

Space Complexity:

We don't use extra space in above algorithm. So `O(1)`.

Comment: @endi: The code I have posted is in `C++`

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni He probably has not learned about vectors yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
int min=A[0]
for(int i=1;i<sizeof(A);i++)
{
   if(min>A[i])
   {
       min=A[i];
   }
}
//the minimum element is 'min'
```

Comment: The above should throw an exception if `A` is empty